# How to remove limitation of number of mails sent

Tags: email, smtp

I'm using [Argosoft MiniMail Server](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/MiniMail/Default.aspx) for testing my drupal [SMTP](http://www.drupal.org/smtp) module.
But it allows me to send only 5 emails. I will be using my hosting providers SMTP settings after I host the site online. But, I need to test it first on local machine first. And due to the limitations on the number of mails, I am not able to do so.
Please suggest any alternatives. here is the snapshot of the settings I need. I tried using gmail, but it's not working.
[image: snapshot]

Comment: Could you clarify? Which settings did you use to configure gmail? Is this on a local machine? Does your ISP block smtp ports (25, 465, 587) as is sometimes the case?

Comment: @jfoucher I changed the image.. and i have configured my outlook for port 25. And my ISP doesn't block the mentioned ports.